# Outputing video and audio from file to virtual webcam and microphone

Tags: pulseaudio, webcam, microphone, ffmpeg

I'm currently trying to get a simple way to share a video with audio using Zoom (but not using the screen sharing).

The only way to really do it is to have the video sent to a virtual webcam and the audio to a virtual microphone, and use those in Zoom.

I looked around and found several solutions using ffmpeg, and they nearly work: i can usually manage to get the video, or the audio, sometimes both but not for long... It's a bit erratic!

Here is my current solution :

```
#Activating virtual webcam:
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback

# Load the "module-pipe-source" module to read audio data from a FIFO special file. 
# (unload first, otherwise it doesn't seem to work again...)
pactl unload-module module-pipe-source
pactl load-module module-pipe-source source_name=virtmic file=/home/hugh/virtmic/virtmic format=s16le rate=16000 channels=1

#use ffmpeg to output video to webcam and audio to virtmic
ffmpeg -re -i input.mp4 -map 0:v -f v4l2 /dev/video3 -map 0:a -f s16le -ar 16000 -ac 1 - > /home/hugh/virtmic/virtmic
```

This has worked, but sometimes it doesn't, sometimes it crashes, sometimes the video stops as soon as it is displayed... And I can pinpoint why and when!

Would you have a more robust solution ?

Thanks!

Comment: Why is screen sharing not a viable option?

Comment: When you share your screen with Zoom, it takes up the whole screen (when you stream the Zoom output to a website like Facebook, Youtube or Twitch). And that isn't viable for what we want to do. We are doing improvised shows on Twitch.tv :)

We're looking for a way to have audio and video coming from a participant feed.

Comment: I tried your command, i have bad audio in skype. Could it be that the audio format and/or codec are not the right ones? I also get black video. Otoh it works with ffmpeg and x11grab (  `ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 15 -s 1280x720 -i :0.0+0,0 -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -threads 0 -f v4l2 /dev/video6`  ), so not sure what's wrong with the video